# How to retrieve docstrings from functions and variables?

Tags: elisp, doc-strings

I'm trying to write a function that will retrieve the docstrings from any sexps in a file that match `(def.*)`.

I'd want to both be able to retrieve any functions/macros, as well as any variables that are defined.  For variables I would want the docstring, while for any functions I would also want the argument lists.

Comment: To clarify: do you have an Elisp source file (my interpretation), or do you have a bunch of variables and functions in the current Emacs environment (Constantine's interpretation)? And if the first interpretation, do you really want all `(def…)` sexps, not just top-level specs? Or the intermediate interpretation of the functions and variables that would be defined if the file is loaded? Or a more relaxed definition that includes such top-level forms as  `(when nil (defun …))`)?

Comment: I had initially wanted the first, however based on Constantine's interpretation I was able to get a functional implementation that got me what I needed.  Goal is to convert elisp source into documentation (written in Org) based on Docstrings.

Comment: With the second interpretation, the built-in `describe-function` and friends do quite a good part of what you want (docstring and arguments list).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the goal is to get information about functions and variables *already in the environment*:

- For docstrings of functions and macros, see the `documentation` function.
- For variable docstrings, use `documentation-property`; for example:

  ```
  (documentation-property
   'user-init-file 'variable-documentation)
  ```
- For function arity and the argument list, see [this Emacs.SE question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/971/argspec-or-arity-of-a-bytecode-function-in-emacs-24), the answer, and comments to the question.

(I found this by pressing `C-h k C-h f` and skimming the source code of `describe-function` (same for variable docstrings, but studying `describe-variable`).)

To analyze an Emacs Lisp source code file, assuming that the goal is to get information about top-level `def.*` forms, one can do something similar to the following.

```
(defun get-defun-info (buffer)
  "Get information about all `defun' top-level sexps in a buffer
BUFFER. Returns a list with elements of the form (symbol args docstring)."
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (save-excursion
      (save-restriction
        (widen)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (let (result)
          ;; keep going while reading succeeds
          (while (condition-case nil
                     (progn
                       (read (current-buffer))
                       (forward-sexp -1)
                       t)
                   (error nil))
            (let ((form (read (current-buffer))))
              (cond
               ((not (listp form))      ; if it's not a list, skip it
                nil)
               ((eq (nth 0 form) 'defun) ; if it's a defun, collect info
                (let ((sym (nth 1 form))
                      (args (nth 2 form))
                      (doc (when (stringp (nth 3 form)) (nth 3 form))))
                  (push (list sym args doc) result))))))
          result)))))
```

This can be easily extended to `defvar`, `defconst`, etc.

To handle `defun` appearing *inside* top-level forms one would have to descend *into* these forms, possibly using recursion.

Comment: +1 for telling readers how to find this info themselves. That's the more important lesson of the two that you taught.

Comment: @Drew It appears we are in a strange situation: the goal of this site is to make itself obsolete… This would make an interesting discussion in chat :)

Comment: @SeanAllred Teaching people to learn doesn't stop the questions, it only makes them better.

Comment: +1 to Malabarba. The purpose of this site should (IMHO) be to **answer what Emacs itself cannot** answer or does not answer *well* or *easily*. Analogy: For site [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/) a reason for closing questions is that "*Questions that can be answered using* ***commonly available references*** are off-topic*". (StackOverflow is similar.) We need not be as extreme, saying that questions that Emacs itself can answer are *off-topic*, but the same idea should apply: get users to *try to find the answer first*. In our case, that means by **asking Emacs**.

Comment: @Drew Fair points :)